# Copy and paste loop through 2 sets of ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an excel sheet. I have titles of data entries, which I wish to copy to other locations on the sheet. The titles range from c3 to c122, and I intend to copy and paste them in cells 70 rows apart. The code below doesn't suffice; I am given error 450 (wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment).

```
Option Explicit
Sub Titles()
Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    For i = 151 To 8971 Step 70
        For n = 3 To 122 Step 1
            Cells.Value(i, 3) = "c" & n
    Next n
Next i

End Sub
```

I desire to have what is in each of cells C3:C122 to be copied into C150, C220,...,C8791. Is this a good approach? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot wrong here.

1. The double for loop is not required.  If the code did work, it would overwrite `Cells.Value(i, 3)` 120 times on each iteration of `i`
2. `Cells` on its own refers to all the cells on the Active Sheet
3. `Cells.Value` returns the cell values as a variant array, in this case a 1,048,576 x 16,384 array
4. `"c" & n` creates a string (eg `c3`) not a cell reference

Try someting like this (note, please check the initial value of `rw` as there is a contradiction in your post 150 vs 151)

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim rw As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("C3:C122")
    rw = 151 '<--- check if this is right

    For Each cl In rng.Cells
        ws.Cells(rw, 3).Value = cl.Value
        rw = rw + 70
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax on `Cells.Value(i, 3)` is wrong it should be `Cells(i, 3).Value`
Change that and see if everything works as you wanted.